# Is it possible that $2-2\cos^2x$ is equivalent to $1-(2\cos^2x-1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There is this exercise and for the first time in my life, I don't want to go to see the solution. Instead, I'm more asking of a tiny help to see if I'm right in my conclusion

<strike>Kids are getting concerned about this math fascination and I said to them it is for their good...</strike>

Humor aside, let's crack on. This is my equation below:

$$ \sin 2x \tan x = 1 - \cos( 2x)$$

$RHS$ is equal to $1- (2\cos^2x-1)$

So I started $LHS$ and eventually, I found this below

$$ (2-2\cos^2x)$$

I'm not good in maths as many of you but intuitively, I can yet feel that my solution is equivalent to the $RHS$ I mentioned above. However, something is missing to me but I cannot say where...

$$(2-2\cos^2x)  \equiv 1- (2\cos^2x-1)$$

Thanks again for your patience in bearing with me

Comment: $$1- (2\cos^2x-1) = 1-2*\cos^2x+1= (2-2\cos^2x)$$ was this your question ? Not sure if i understood it Right.

Comment: Hi @residuence, I've amended a bit my question. see the equivalence

Comment: The identity is true, but you need to explain stepwise how you reached $2 - 2 cos^2 x$ for the $LHS$

Comment: Hi @trueblueanil let me do that before I go to do the chores. What I know is how I can reach the equivalence...

Comment: The two terms are equal (equivalent), but the reason why has nothing to do with trigonometry and all to do with basic algebra. Note that $-(2\cos^2 x - 1)$ is exactly the same as $-2\cos^2x + 1$.

Comment: Hi @Arthur, you nailed it correctly. Damn

Comment: @residuence you made me realize something I had a hard time dealing when younger. Please use your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$1- (2\cos^2x-1) = 1-2*\cos^2x+1= (2-2\cos^2x)$$ 
Greetings.